# How to get unique numbers using randomint python?

Tags: python, loops, random, while-loop, int

I am creating a 'Euromillions Lottery generator' just for fun and I keep getting the same numbers printing out. How can I make it so that I get random numbers and never get the same number popping up:

```
from random import randint

numbers = randint(1,50)

stars = randint(1,11)


print "Your lucky numbers are: ", numbers, numbers, numbers, numbers, numbers

print "Your lucky stars are: " , stars, stars
```

The output is just:

```
>>> Your lucky numbers are:  41 41 41 41 41
>>> Your lucky stars are:  8 8
>>> Good bye!
```

How can I fix this?

Regards

Comment: `numbers = randint(1, 50)` does not mean "`numbers` shall be a magical thing that evaluates `randint(1, 50)` each time I look at it and tells me the result". It means "evaluate `randint(1, 50)` right now; `numbers` shall be a name for the result".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up a set of numbers then shuffle and slice the set.

```
from random import shuffle
numbers  = list(range(1,51))
shuffle(numbers)
draw = numbers[:6]
print(draw)
```

Comment: `shuffle` modifies the list in-place and returns `None`.

Comment: This is not including `50`, `randint(1, 50)` includes the endpoint in the possible values.

Comment: And in python3, shuffle does not work with iterable objects… edited with list(range(1, 50))

Comment: Thanks for the edits, a much improved answer over my original. I've clearly been using other Heathen languages for too long as I found the fact that shuffle is in-place rather than returning a new shuffled set surprising, but you learn every day.

Comment: Note that `random.sample()` works *great* with `range()` in Python 3, or `xrange()` in Python 2, because it implements `__len__` and `__getitem__` (it is a proper sequence object).

Comment: If your set is very large, shuffling the whole thing just to pick 6 may be too slow. You can also do a partial Fisher-Yates, or use Floyd's algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

You are generating **one** number then printing that out several times.

Generate several numbers instead:

```
print "Your lucky numbers are: ", randint(1,50), randint(1,50), randint(1,50), randint(1,50), randint(1,50)
```

or generate a list:

```
numbers = [randint(1,50) for _ in range(5)]
print "Your lucky numbers are: ", ' '.join(numbers)
```

or better still, generate all permissible numbers (using `range()` then pick a sample from that:

```
possible_numbers = range(1, 51)  # end point is not included
numbers = random.sample(possible_numbers, 5)
print "Your lucky numbers are: ", ' '.join(map(str, numbers))
```

Now `numbers` is guaranteed to consist of entirely unique numbers.

The `numbers` variable does not magically update every time you print it because it refers only to the *result* of `random.randint(1, 50)`.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: The biggest problem for the OP is the concept of what a variable refers to here. Solving the uniqueness problem is the *next* step.

Comment: Ok. But OP has mentioned in the question that the same numbers should not repeat

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: yes, indeed, that's why my answer includes information about how to do that. But you cannot just throw code at someone that is still coming to grips with fundamental concepts.

Comment: After all the elaborations, this is a much better answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

`numbers = randint(1,50)` assigns **one** random number to a variable. And you repeatedly use this one random number. Same goes for `stars`

Try this instead:

```
print "Your lucky numbers are: ", randint(1,50), randint(1,50), randint(1,50), randint(1,50), randint(1,50)
```

Or you can create a list of numbers and get a random sample:

```
numbers = range(1,50)
print "Your lucky numbers are: ", ' '.join(map(str, random.sample(numbers, 5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `randint` 5 times for your lucky numbers. You only call it once, and display the result 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`random.sample(range(range_to_which_random_be_generated), number_of_numbers_to_generate)`

example
`random.sample(range(50),6)`
would generate 6 different numbers in range 0 to 49

Comment: No, this generates numbers between 0 and 49, but the principle is otherwise sound.

Answer (score 0):

One way i would suggest is to put the generated numbers in a list, and check if the next number is not in the list list before adding it to the list

```
numbers=[randint(1,50)]
i=1
while i<n:  # n is the number of random numbers you want to generate
    x=randint(1,50)
    if not x in numbers:
        i+=1
        numbers.append(x)
```

The problem in your code is that you generate only a single random number and print it four times